# How to use link preload for one of several font types

Tags: html, css, sass

I have woff and woff2 font types, browser detect one of them. If i use link preload, then browser download both files. How preload only appropriate font file?

sass

```
@font-face
  font-family: SegoeUI
  font-display: swap
  src: url('/fonts/Segoe UI Semibold.woff2') format('woff2'), url('/fonts/Segoe UI Semibold.woff') format('woff')
  font-weight: 600
  font-style: normal
  font-stretch: normal
  unicode-range: U+0020-1FFE
```

html

```
<link rel="preload" as="font" href="/fonts/Segoe UI Semibold.woff" type="font/woff" crossorigin>
        <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/fonts/Segoe UI Semibold.woff2" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preload Fonts by

```
<link rel="preload" href="fonts/Segoe UI Semibold.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preload" href="fonts/Segoe UI Semibold.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I don't thing there is a way to download fonts which are required, you have to specify which font you want to use.

Comment: This response doesn't answer the question. OP already knows how to preload fonts, what they don't know is how to preload only the font the browser will actually pick. I don't know either.